# How to disable touch events on a View?

Tags: java, android, touch, opengl-es-2.0, ontouchlistener

My (OpenGL ES 2.0) app has a splashscreen which is basically an Android **View** displayed over my **GLSurfaceView**.

I do all my initial setup on an AsyncTask and then (out of necessity), load my bitmaps/textures on the GLRendering thread in onSurfaceCreated.  Once everything has loaded, I dismiss my splashscreen.

Everything works as expected apart from one thing.  The splashscreen still accepts input and if the screen is touched just after the app is launched, I (obviously) get an null pointer exception.

I simply create my view like so:

```
splashscreen = new SplashScreen(getApplication(), width, height);  //Where SplashScreen is a custom class that extends View
```

I then add it to my layout like so:

```
layout.add(myView);        //My GLSurfaceView
layout.add(splashscreen);  //The splashscreen View
setContectView(layout);
```

Once everything has loaded, I simply remove the (splashscreen) View to reveal my GLSurfaceView underneath:

```
layout.removeView(splashscreen);
splashscreen=null;  //Null it
```

currently, in my onTouch method, to get around the issue, I have put a check in place like so:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(splashscreen==null){
    //Do touch related stuff here
    }

    return true;

}
```

This does work, however, I'm sure it's not the cleanest way to achieve what I'm after.

I've tried this:

```
splashscreensetClickable(false);
```

and

```
layout.setClickable(false);
```

as well as **setEnabled(false)**

Nothing seems to work, but I'm **sure** there must be a way of doing this.......

Comment: Can you clarify a couple things? "_The splashscreen still accepts input and if the screen is touched just after the app is launched, I (obviously) get an null pointer exception._" Why do you want your splashscreen to not block touch input while it is visible? Why exactly is this NPE occurring?

Comment: Hi @TrevorSiemens, the splashscreen simply shoulnd't accept input.  There is no reason for it to.  The  user can press the home button while everything is loading if they want out.  But, the splashscreen shouldn't be 'interactive'.  The nullpointer is happening because once the screen is pressed, it then starts running the app and calls the GLRenderer, which tries to act upon objects which don't yet exist... hope this makes sense :-)  However, it is enough to know that the splashscreen shouldn't accept input, therefore, it should be disabled!

Comment: I am thinking a couple things: Even though the splash screen should not be 'interactive' it should still be accepting the touch input. It simply shouldn't do anything with it. You can do this by overriding onTouchEvent of the splash screen, and simply return true. This will allow it to block touch events on the views below, but nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSiemens, this works perfectly! I must admit, I'm still not fully sure why it works, I'm guessing overriding onTouchEvent simply 'scoops up' touch events for this View (the splash screen), whereas without this, it passes the touch events to the Main Activiy's onTouch method?? If you want to put this into an answer, I'll accept it!  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you will want the splash screen to prevent the user from doing anything while it is present. You can actually do this, because views in android, as in other UI frameworks, have a hierarchy in which touch events cascade.

Even though you don't want the splash screen to be interactive, you can still steal all of the touch events that occur on it, and just do nothing with them. The answer itself is to override `onTouchEvent` in your `SplashScreen` class with:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true; // Splash screen is consuming all touch events on it.
}
```

Returning `true` in this basically says that nothing under this view should receive a touch event. As long as it is visible and over top of the surface view, your surface view will not get any touch events. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) for details.